# Best practice for managing OrientDB connections in Express.js / Web Applications

Tags: express, orientdb, orientjs, oriento

What is the recommended way to manage [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) connections in Express.js or any web application for that matter? Connection per request? Would be using the [oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) Node.js driver

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oriento, you can try connection pooling, as per [PR #7](https://github.com/codemix/oriento/pull/7) you can set it like this:

```
var server = Oriento({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'foo',
  pool: {
    max: 10 // use a maximum of 10 sockets in the pool
  }
});
```

Please bear in mind that at some point connection pooling config was hidden from Oriento's README due to *issues with thread safety [...] in orientdb* ([reference](https://github.com/codemix/oriento/commit/a754c48b824f159b8a2e7ba9c5767b3b0b54b1e6)). You may want to clear that before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dario. I am interested to see when the connection should be opened and closed. Should we be opening a connection per request and closing it at the end of the request?

Comment: Well, opening a connection per request could exhaust the maximum number of OrientDB connections (50 by default, I believe) so I don't recommend that. I recommend either using a single connection or a pool (mind the caveat I mentioned earlier) which should be setup before receiving requests. Oriento will reconnect by itself if the existing connection fails. Closing and opening connections may also introduce an overhead.

Comment: Normal web practice would be to open a connection, preferably a transaction, at the start of the request and then commit/close at the end of the request so connections are released. Going to run some tests...

Comment: I'm not sure what "Normal web practice" is, I guess that will depend on the source you quote. Using a connection pool is very common to reduce the overhead of connecting and disconnecting to the DB. For example, sequelize, a popular SQL ORM suggests a pool with 5 connections in its [getting started docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/). Every time a query is issued one of those connections will be used and then released for other queries to use, without the need of establishing new connections.